# What is the simplification of AB + BC + (~B)C?

Tags: boolean-algebra, propositional-logic

AB + C is not the answer. 
The correct answer is AB + BC.  HOW?

Comment: How should ~BC be parsed? ​ ​

Comment: ~ sign is for negation, it's (not)B.  Did you mean to ask this?

Comment: Yes, since parsing it as ​ not BC ​ instead would presumably give a different answer. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes that would.

Comment: The correct answer might be incorrect. It happens.

Comment: That can be the case yes, still I want to be sure so following are the four options for this question:               (a) AB + BC     (b) BC + (~B)C       (c) AB + (~B)C                (d) AB

Answer (score 1):

Imo there is a problem in the proposed options. Indeed,

$AB+BC+(\neg B)C=AB+(B+\neg B)C=AB+C$

You can check that also comparing the truth-tables of
$AB+BC+(\neg B)C$ and $AB+C$.

Comment: Thank you, my answer is also AB + C and I also tried k-map but didn't get the answer which can mean that the given options are incorrect.

Comment: @CuriousCS The answer given by the exercise book is simply incorrect. It happens.